# .htaccess -- Disable mod_pagespeed in specific browsers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-pagespeed

I would like to disable `mod_pagespeed` using `.htaccess` for specific browsers.  I figured this would be a simple matter of creating a `RewriteCond` and a subsequent `RewriteRule` specifying the skipping of **Chrome** and then another set of conditions that would turn the mod off for ths listed browsers.  I don't get any errors, but the rule seems to not be functioning  --  The **Firefox** broswer is still showing the optimizations from `mod_pagespeed`.   Here is the `.htaccess` I attempted:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(Mozilla.*|Safari.*|Other.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule Mod_Pagespeed off
```

As you can see it's pretty straight forward.   Am I not allowed to turn a module off within a `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule`?

It is also worth mentioning that I have cleared the `pagespeed` cache every time I "test" this --  So I am not seeing a cached version.

I have also tried the following to no avail:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'Chrome'">
    # configuration for Chrome
</If>
<Else>
    <IfModule pagespeed_module>
        ModPagespeed off
    </IfModule>
</Else>
```

**Pagespeed Version 1.12.34.2-0**

[image: Mod_Pagespeed Version]

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed on
    ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig on
    AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
    ModPagespeedFileCachePath            "/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/"
    ModPagespeedLogDir "/var/log/pagespeed"
    ModPagespeedSslCertDirectory "/etc/ssl/certs"
    ModPagespeedFileCacheInodeLimit        500000
    ModPagespeedImageMaxRewritesAtOnce      20

    # ModPagespeedNumRewriteThreads 4
    # ModPagespeedNumExpensiveRewriteThreads 4

    ModPagespeedPrivateNotVaryForIE on

    # Lossy image recompression quality (0 to 100, -1 just strips metadata):
    ModPagespeedImageRecompressionQuality 85

    # Jpeg recompression quality (0 to 100, -1 uses ImageRecompressionQuality):
    ModPagespeedJpegRecompressionQuality -1
    ModPagespeedJpegRecompressionQualityForSmallScreens 70
    #
    # WebP recompression quality (0 to 100, -1 uses ImageRecompressionQuality):
    ModPagespeedWebpRecompressionQuality 80
    ModPagespeedWebpRecompressionQualityForSmallScreens 70
    ModPagespeedWebpTimeoutMs 5000

    ModPagespeedMaxSegmentLength 1024

    # ModPagespeedCombineAcrossPaths off

    <Location /pagespeed_admin>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        SetHandler pagespeed_admin
    </Location>
    <Location /pagespeed_global_admin>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        SetHandler pagespeed_global_admin
    </Location>

    ModPagespeedStatisticsLogging on

    ModPagespeedMessageBufferSize 100000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I doubt this can be done, and am quite curious about *why* you want to do it.

Comment: It's the easiest way to configure for browsers (who are only 4% of our traffic) who do not support webp image compression.

Comment: But PageSpeed *already* detects browsers that don't support WebP images. https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/reference-image-optimize#convert_jpeg_to_webp "This filter converts JPEG to lossily-encoded WebP format **if the latter is supported by the browser**."

Comment: I can tell you for fact that Internet Explorer's **source** shows: `src="/imageserver/Logo.png,,Mic.VkxRcxN4Sr.webp,Mic.g83Dd2AHHQ.webp.pagespeed.ic.kLcKYTA9mX.webp"`  --  So what is my issue?

Comment: How up-to-date is your PageSpeed module? http://christianheilmann.com/2015/06/08/ua-sniffing-issue-outdated-mod-pagespeed-sending-webp-images-to-microsoft-edge/

Comment: I have edited with my pagespeed version.  --  Still IE is "seeing" the webp files

Comment: Can you share your PageSpeed config?

Comment: Added config to OP